# MVC and EF5 scaffolding project nullable fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have created a MVC and EF5 scaffolding project. The purpose is to be able to provide an interface to the database quick and simple with no fancy stuff.

The problem I am facing is that in the database a field `F1` in `TableA` is `nullable` and also foreign key coming from another `TableB`. The view generated for creating an entry in `TableA` provides a dropdownlist for field `F1` showing all the values coming from `TableB` but there is no way to enter/select `null` in the view.

How do we solve this problem. As there are instances when the value will be `null`. And I can not create a `null` entry in `TableB` just for this because that field is primary key there and can not be `null`.

The potential duplicate mentioned does not deal with setting up MVC and EF5, it just tells how to do the coding for adding a null value to the dropdown list, I am looking for something that possibly use some setting somewhere in the process of creating the scaffolding project to handle this, if it is possible at all.

Comment: A listbox (for selecting multiple items) of a dropdownlist (for selecting a single item)?

Comment: I am selecting single item so yes the dropdownlist.

Comment: The just add the 3rd parameter to your `@Html.DropDownListFor()` method to generate a `null` option

Comment: @jdphenix How it is done in MVC and EF that link does not say anything. I am not coding it myself, it is the scaffolding project. Do I need to change some setting, or I have to code it explicitly?

Comment: The top answer actually has the exact thing you need to do in order to get the behavior you want. Yes, it does involve coding it. (More accurately, I'm not sure if the scaffolder can handle this, it's been a long while since I've used it)

Comment: Scaffolding just provides a basic outline. You need to modify it.

Comment: Regarding your edit and _if it is possible at all_ - No its not (unless you were to create your own T4 templates)

Comment: @StephenMuecke there is no DropDownListFor() method
The close enough simple DropDownList() and LabelFor()

Comment: In the DropDownList() this is what I have
Html.DropDownList("MenuItem", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })

Comment: Of course there is! (but unless you want to stay 'Novice' forever, you will not use scaffolding, and not use data models in views, and you will certainly never use the weak typed `HtmlHelper` methods)